# Vue3 - possible to bind prop to background-image in style?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Say I have the following component:

```vue
<template>
  <q-layout view="lHh lpR lFf">
    <q-page-container>
      <div class="image-container">
        Image Container
      </div>
      <slot />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script lang='ts' setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    image: { type: String, required: true, default: '' },
  });
  // console.log(image);
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .image-container {
    display: none;

    @media (min-width: $breakpoint-sm-min) {
      background: v-bind("props.image") no-repeat left center fixed;
      display: block;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
    }
  }
</style>
```

I can verify that the prop comes through as a string correctly, and according to the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#state-driven-dynamic-css) I can use `v-bind` to more easily insert dynamic values to the styles.

The image doesn't show up though, and I see this when I open the inspector:
[image]

I've also tried variations of wrapping the `v-bind` inside of `url()`, but nothing appears to be working. Is this just not yet possible with Vue3?

Note: I am currently using Vue v3.2.29.

Comment: That works fine in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-lxeqtn?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FImageContainer.vue). Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: @tony19 one difference I'm noticing between your demo and my code is that your image is contained locally in the src/assets directory, whereas I'm pulling this string from a third party API. That's why I was messing around with trying to also wrap the v-bind with a `url()` property on background.

Comment: Here's a [demo with a remote URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-starter-avftqq?file=src%2FApp.vue). The problem is likely in your implementation, so a reproduction would be helpful.

Comment: @tony19 ah! including the `url()` in the parent did the trick. I'll post an update with the answer, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @tony19 in the comments, we figured out that I wasn't *too* far off. Essentially, rather than trying to use `url()` in the css, I've moved that up to the parent that is passing down the prop.

**Parent.vue**

```vue
<template>
  <Child :image="`url(${image})`">
    ...
  </Child>
</template>
```

**Child.vue**

```vue
<template>
  <q-layout view="lHh lpR lFf">
    <q-page-container>
      <div class="image-container">
        Image Container
      </div>
      <slot />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script lang='ts' setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    image: { type: String, required: true, default: '' },
  });
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .image-container {
    display: none;

    @media (min-width: $breakpoint-sm-min) {
      background: v-bind("props.image") no-repeat left center fixed;
      display: block;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
    }
  }
</style>
```